# How to refer new JLabel to existing one

Tags: java, swing, reference, jlabel

I created a jframe using netbean, and added a jlabel (changeLbl) to that jframe. after that I added a jbutton to that jframe. now I need to create a new jlabel and assign it to that jlabel (changeLbl) when click the jbutton. so I wrote the code like bellow, but it didn't  change the jlabel text. I can't understand why ?
as I know changeLbl should be referenced to the new jlabel when click the button 
complete source code can be found [here](https://github.com/Roledenez/JTestExample)

```
   private void changeBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    changeLbl = new JLabel();
    changeLbl.setText("Hello World!");
    changeLbl.revalidate();
    changeLbl.repaint();
    changeLbl.update(changeLbl.getGraphics());
}
```

Comment: why do you create new lable .can't you change text of existing one ? .post additional codes somewhere we can easily view .also if you wonder to know why it doesn't work probably because of your layout .but as @AndrewThompson says plz don't create new lable

Comment: @FastSnail I would promote that to *"**Don't** create a new label, just **set the text** of the existing instance"*.

Comment: as java reference variable works, this should be work, my problem is why this shouldn't work

Comment: @SelaruSinbath i don't see you call `panel.add(changeLbl);` if you don't add lables to a component ,how could it be visible ??? but again don't create and add change text of existing one as AndrewThompson  answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create a new label, just *set the text* of the existing instance.  To do that:

### Change

```
changeLbl = new JLabel();
changeLbl.setText("Hello World!");
changeLbl.revalidate();
changeLbl.repaint();
changeLbl.update(changeLbl.getGraphics());
```

### To

```
changeLbl.setText("Hello World!");
```

Comment: your code is work, but I can't understand why my code isn't work ? I expect that do be work according to java reference variable works

Comment: @SelaruSinbath you never add lables to a container `panel.add(changeLbl);` ??

Comment: *"I expect that do be work according to java reference variable works"* A reference to an object is different to an object appearing on-screen, and programming down to understand references should not be trying to do that using GUI elements, but simpler objects.  Doing it with GUI objects is a complicated way to try and understand a simple principle.